# Angular property decorators throwing "Property 'x' has no initializer..." error in latest VSCode

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm going to reference the Angular guide [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) and use this sample code.

Since I last updated my Visual Studio Code I have started getting red underlines in my Angular component `.ts` files under properties in my components that are decorated with Angular decorators such as `@Input`. In the example code below I would see a red underline under `@Input() hero: Hero;` and `@Input('master') masterName: string;`:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-child',
  template: `
    <h3>{{hero.name}} says:</h3>
    <p>I, {{hero.name}}, am at your service, {{masterName}}.</p>
  `
})
export class HeroChildComponent {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
  @Input('master') masterName: string;
}
```

Here is the error message of the red underlines:

> [ts] Property 'masterName' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

I don't know why these suddenly showed up and I'd like them to go away. What I would *not* like to do is initialize to some throwaway value, this may be fine for `string` but for classes like `Hero` I definitely don't want to have to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Check your tsconfig.json file and ensure `strictPropertyInitialization` is false.

See "Strict Class Initialization" section of this document for more information: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html

Note: If you have

```
"strict": true,
```

set in your tsconfig.json file, it now will automatically set this new strict property and cause you to see all of these notifications.

So you can change it to:

```
"strict": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
```

Comment: I did have `"strict": true` and adding `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` did the trick!

Comment: but setting "strictPropertyInitialization" to false will introduce a wide range of errors in the app.....

Answer (score 24):

As of TypeScript 2.7 the answer is to use [Definite Assignment Assertions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)

Angular Syntax

```
export class HeroChildComponent {
    @Input('master') masterName!: string;
```

AngularJS + TypeScript Syntax

```
export class HeroChildComponent {
    public masterName!: string;
```

This allows for specific properties to be marked as 'Yeah I am declaring this will be here so leave it alone'. This way you can opt-out in the cases you know to be true and the default behavior of checking for initialization is still on by default.

However... at the time of this comment 2/26/2018 Webstorm and potentially other IDE's do not accept it as valid syntax so the only way to get around it is to turn off "strictPropertyInitialization" in the tsConfig.

[Webstorm 2018 EAP 181.3741](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/02/webstorm-2018-1-eap-181-3741/) says it includes the needed updates to support [Definite Assignment Assertions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)

Judging by [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43296) I think latest VSCode does support [Definite Assignment Assertions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)

Answer (score 1):

**solution 1:**

make an initializer

```
name: string;
constructor() {
    this.name = '';
}
```

**solution 2:**

make the property optional

```
name?: string;
or
name: string|undefined;
```

**solution 3:**

Solution by @DeborahK.
Do it in tsconfig.json

```
"strict": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
```